# Automatically removing feature branches on GitHub once they're merged to master

Tags: github, jenkins, webhooks

We have over 100 repos which follow the  github workflow https://guides.github.com/introduction/flow/. Ideally, when people are merging their code, they'll also click the Delete Branch button, but unfortunately, that step gets missed pretty often. I'm looking for a way to automatically delete branches which have been merged to the master branch. I'm thinking it should either be an organizational level webhook or integrated into our existing Jenkins system. I'm hoping that someone has already written this tool. Anyone?